# Find combinations of rows grouped by a column by picking 1 row from each group in dataframe

Tags: r, combinations

I have a dataframe which can be grouped by column. Each row in a particular group has a unique id. By picking 1 row from each group, I want to form all possible combinations possible.

I have tried to solve it by `combn()` and `expand.grid()`. But was not able to get the desired solution.

### I have following type of data

```
Col1  id  Unique id
A     1     A_1
A     2     A_2
B     1     B_1
C     1     C_1
C     2     C_2
C     3     C_3
```

### I want something like this:

### Groups or dataframes for following type:

```
(A_1,B_1,C_1)
(A_1,B_1,C_2)
(A_1,B_1,C_3)
(A_2,B_1,C_1)
(A_2,B_1,C_2)
(A_2,B_1,C_3)
```

Here I have shown only 3 groups that are A,B,C.
I real dataset I can have any number of groups and each row can have any number of ids.
Please help me for this with code or logic whatever possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly is the output constructed?

Comment: Basically I have different number of rows in each group and they have multiple columns also. I want combination of rows and create a list of dataframe from from them. Then I want to carry out specific functions to each dataframe

Comment: But how is your output here constructed? I can't immediately see the connection to get fx (A_1,B_1,C_3) .

Comment: Basically A_1, B_1, C_3 will be rows in the Dataframe. Similarly there will be a data frame for each combination. I want to store all these Dataframe in a list and then carry out a particular function on each Dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split `unique_id` by `Col1` then use `expand.grid()`.

```
expand.grid(split(df$Unique_id, f = df$Col1))

    A   B   C
1 A_1 B_1 C_1
2 A_2 B_1 C_1
3 A_1 B_1 C_2
4 A_2 B_1 C_2
5 A_1 B_1 C_3
6 A_2 B_1 C_3
```